# Returning multiple values from callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I have a cross platform app built using Monaca and AngularJS.
The app uses the Camera plugin that allows users to take photos.

A have a function that takes the pictures, and in that function I want to return a few values when the photo is successfully captured.

Below is my method that calls the takePicture() function, along with trying to access the returned values. The 2 functions below are called from different Controllers/Services as well.

**Controller**

```
// Take photo
$scope.takePicture = function () {
    var test = Photo.takePicture();
    alert("photoCaptured: " + test.photoCaptured + "\nphotoName" + test.photoName); // Error here
};
```

Below is the *takePicture()* function that fires the Camera and returns the values at the *onSuccess* callback

**Service**

```
// Get the main app.js module
var photo = angular.module("photo", []);
photo.service("Photo", function () {
    var myFunctions = {
        // Take picture
        takePicture: function () {

            var onSuccess = function (imageURI) {
                var photoCaptured, photoName;
                return { photoCaptured: true, photoName: imageURI } // Should return multiple values
            }
            var onFail = function (error) {
                alert("AN ERROR HAS OCCURED" + "\nPhoto capture failed." + error);
            }

            var options = { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI};
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
        },
    }
    return myFunctions;
});
```

However, the *test* throws error *Cannot read property 'photoCaptured' of undefined.*

How do I access the values returned from the *onSuccess* callback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See the duplicate question for your issue. By the way this code doesn't make sense `var photoCaptured, photoName;
                return { photoCaptured: true, photoName: imageURI }` you are going to create an object and those are properties names, not variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Andreas - the answer at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) duplicate question solved my issue. In my case *$q.defer* did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `test` to the return value of `Photo.takePicture()`, so if that function does not return a value, `test` will remain `undefined` and trying to access any property of `test` will throw the error `Cannot read property x of undefined`.